# Issue raising multiple PropertyChanged events using PropertyChanged delegate

Tags: c#, silverlight, properties, delegates, propertychanged

I have a class RuleDependency and two properties `IsNull` and `ValueTypeEnabled`. 
We are using silverlight for our UI and I wish to have the following functionality.
When the `IsNull` Property changed I wish to raise the `PropertyChanged` event for the second property: `ValueTypeEnabled`. Note that this is a partial class as an extension of a class that comes from a webservice and I have the `IsNull` `Property` just in the reference, so I cannot `RaisePropertyChanged` for my `ValueTypeEnabled` on the setter of `IsNull Property`.
I have done the following:

```
 public partial class RuleDependency
    {
        public RuleDependency() {
            PropertyChanged += RuleDependency_PropertyChanged;            
        }

        private void RuleDependency_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.PropertyName == "IsNull") {
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("IsNull");
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("ValueTypeEnabled");
            }
        }

        private bool _valueTypeEnabled;


        public bool ValueTypeEnabled
        {
            get {
                return  (IsNull == null || !IsNull.Value)
            }
        }
    }
```

For unknown reason, modifying `IsNull property` doesn't raise the event for `ValueTypeEnabled` property.

Answer (score 0):

the issue was that the constructor in this partial class was not called, so the function would not bind to the eventhandler. I fixed it adding this

```
dependencies[i].PropertyChanged += dependencies[i].RuleDependency_PropertyChanged;
```

when using the objects.